# Make visible only one print button in relation with the view criteria I have chosen

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

In one project I have multiple view criteria choosing different attributes from one view object and different print buttons I want to invoke.
This I want to do is when I choose a specific view criteria to display in my page only this print button which match with the view criteria and others become invisible.

Is there any way to know the id or something of view criteria I have select when I run my application?

I am using Jdeveloper 12c deploying on Oracle weblogic.

Comment: Can you add some example code here.I guess the question is too brief.

Comment: how are you "choosing a specific VC?" programmatically/ or from a actionListener like a button or link?

Comment: With a button and using the action file downloader property.